# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I wanted to ask why does this code throw error with `2.3.0.RELEASE` and not with `2.0.6.RELEASE` of Spring Data MongoDB:

```
@Service
public class ServiceX {
    @Autowired private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000) public void scheduled() {
        // I am using mongoTemplate here
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean Spring Boot `2.3.0.RELEASE` and not mongodb. Could you please tell us what kind of starter are you using? `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` or `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive`?

Comment: I am using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MongoTemplate` is an imperative variant. You should use `ReactiveMongoTemplate` instead since you are on Reactive MongoDB. It used to work in older versions but it won't work with Spring Boot `2.3.0.RELASE` and above.

Infact, I created this issue yesterday:

- [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21561)
- [Spring Boot Release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#mongodb)

You can always switch to non reactive variant of Spring Data MongoDB using `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` instead of `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive`.